# Equivalent of .schema in Oracle

Tags: oracle, schema

I have read access on a table in a database and I wanted to get the relational schema. In Sqlite3, I know you could just do .schema . However, I was wondering what the equivalent is in OracleDB. It seems hard to find because they've repurposed the word schema.

Comment: For those of us that don't know SQLite: what does this `.schema` thing do? And what exactly do you mean with "get the relational schema"?

Answer (score 0):

as I understood from this [SQLite link](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html)

> .schema ?TABLE?        Show the CREATE statements
>                            If TABLE specified, only show tables matching
>                            LIKE pattern TABLE.

to get DDL/create statements for Oracle objects you need use package [DBMS_METADATA](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_metada.htm#i1019267)

> Example: Fetch the DDL for all Complete Tables in the Current Schema,
>   Filter Out Nested Tables and Overflow Segments

```
--create test table
create table my_test_table(col1 varchar(50));

--get DDL
SELECT table_name, DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE',u.table_name)
     FROM USER_ALL_TABLES u
     WHERE u.nested='NO' 
     AND (u.iot_type is null or u.iot_type='IOT');

--query result 
    TABLE_NAME  DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE',
1   MY_TEST_TABLE   <CLOB>

--DDL for MY_TEST_TABLE will be
  CREATE TABLE "TESTUSER"."MY_TEST_TABLE" 
   (    "COL1" VARCHAR2(50)
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS"
```